# How to disable right click menu in external launched application

Tags: windows, mouse, external, right-click

**Good day.**

I have a program thats launches an external application. That external app has a right click sub menu on it which I need to disable. Is it possible (without modifying the external app) to disable the right click? Maybe permission or group policies and etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Which application are you launching? I doubt it's possible.. but I could be wrong.

Comment: Wow, looks like it is possible. I'd love to see the solution posted here, when you work it out :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure I wanted to post as I don't have a huge amount of scope on the matter, but it's definatley possible.
If you have a handle to the application (if not you can get one) you can use that to disable right click within the application.

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=190440

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

seems like the most helpful links, it just goes on about how you should hook and then disregard `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_RBUTTONUP`.

I'll try and write up a better thing later with an example.

More links/edits

This link could be useful as it explains that you're going to need to use unmanaged c/c++ to hook using setWindowsHookEx.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/8dd657b5-647b-443b-822d-ebe03ca4033c/

Hope this helps

[EDIT]

I think this can actually be done in a C# application completely. I will post a solution tonight

[/EDIT]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Haven't tried it yet but I will try it soon. If you will provide an example in C#, it'll be great, but do not bother too much.

Comment: I've not done anything in c# before, so it'll be a challenge to say the least :)

Comment: Ok, no problem I'll try to handle it by myself. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a win32 api FAQ.

see news://194.177.96.26/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
where it has often been discussed

Answer (score 0):

I know a brutal solution for Windows. Make a hook on mouse and filter all messages, going to the external program window. It can slow down a whole system a little though.

It's not that comlicated. Here's a tutorial: http://win32assembly.online.fr/tut24.html
Nevermind assembler, it works the same way in any language.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Use this code in script to disable right click